# Como usar guardas com let em Haskell

Tags: haskell

Eu queria fazer esse mesmo problema que calcula as raizes de uma funcao do segundo grau, porem utilizando let.

```
raizes2 :: Float -> Float -> Float -> (Float, Float)
raizes2 a b c 
  |delta < 0 = error "Delta nao pode ser menor que zero"
  |a == 0 = error "A nao pode ser zero"
  |otherwise = ((-b + (sqrt(delta)))/2*a, (-b - (sqrt(delta)))/2*a)
where
delta = (b^2 - 4*a*c)
```

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que usar expressões `case`. Por exemplo:

```
raizes2 :: Float -> Float -> Float -> (Float, Float)
raizes2 a b c = let delta = (b^2 - 4*a*c)
                in case compare delta 0 of
                     LT -> error "Delta nao pode ser menor que zero"
                     _  -> if a == 0
                           then error "A nao pode ser zero"
                           else ( (-b + (sqrt(delta)))/2*a
                                , (-b - (sqrt(delta)))/2*a )
```

Fica um pouco diferente porque `case` só compara igualdades. E o que é comparado é estático, isto é, sempre será o resultado de `compare delta 0`, que pode ser `LT`, `GT` ou `EQ`. Como seus padrões envolvem a comparação não só do valor de `delta`, é preciso usar o caso `_` (que aceita qualquer coisa) e dentro dele criar um `if` (ou outro `case`) para comparar o valor de `a`.

Se quiser ler um pouco sobre essas estruturas, a página sobre `case` está traduzida no [Wikibook em português](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Estruturas_de_controle).

Answer (score 0):

Nao da para usar guardas dentro do let diretamente. As guardas vem antes da definicao da expressao a ser avaliada, e o let ja é essa expressao. Mas um jeito de resolver (deselegantemente) o problema é definir uma funcao auxiliar dentro do let, e nessa definicao usar as guardas

```
raizes2 a b c = let delta = (b^2 - 4*a*c)
                    auxiliar
                        |delta < 0 = error "Delta nao pode ser menor que zero"
                        |a == 0 = error "A nao pode ser zero"
                        |otherwise = ((-b + (sqrt(delta)))/2*a, (-b - (sqrt(delta)))/2*a)
                in auxiliar
```

Como eu falei, deselegante....